# display post category once using foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to display post based on category.
I have created short code to display post
[knowledge_sharing cat="docs" posts_per_page="5"]

code:-

```
function cat_post($atts){

// attributes for shortcode
if (isset($atts['cat'])) {$cat = $atts['cat'];} else {return;}
if (isset($atts['posts_per_page'])) {$posts_per_page = $atts['posts_per_page'];} else {$posts_per_page = -1;}

// get the category posts
$category = get_category_by_slug($cat);
if (!is_object($category)) {return;}
$args = array(
    'cat' => $category->term_id,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'post_type' => 'knowledgeSharingDocs',
    'order'  => 'DESC'
);
$posts = get_posts($args);

// create the list output
if (count($posts) > 0) {

 $cat_title = get_the_category($posts->ID);
 foreach($cat_title as $cd){
            $output .='<div class="category-name do-title dot-symbol ">' .$cd->cat_name. '</div>';
         }
 $output .= '<div class="category-list">';
   foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $output .='<div class="category-boxs">';
           $output .='<div class="category-titles"><a href="'.$link.'">' .$title. '</a></div>';
           $output .='<div class="category-decs">' .$post->post_content. '</div>';
        $output .='</div>';

   }
 $output .= '</div>';  
 return $output;
 }
 }
```

Somehow this code displays only post title and content and not category name.

I want output to be like this:-
Category name
post 1
post2
post 3

Category name once only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the error.log for errors/warnings. there shoult be at least a undef variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example and will help you.

As like Stefano Pascazi told, if you are querying particular category you don't need to use `$cat_title = get_the_category($posts->ID);` because query is returning particular category only.

But if any child category exists for that category we can show posts by splitting all categories by using following example.

```
function cat_post($atts){

    // attributes for shortcode
    if (isset($atts['cat'])) {$cat = $atts['cat'];} else {return;}
    if (isset($atts['posts_per_page'])) {$posts_per_page = $atts['posts_per_page'];} else {$posts_per_page = -1;}

    // get the category posts
    $category = get_category_by_slug($cat);
    if (!is_object($category)) {return;}
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'post_type' => 'knowledgeSharingDocs',
        'order'  => 'DESC'
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    $output = "";
    if (count($posts) > 0) {

        $op = array();  
        foreach ($posts as $post) { 

            $pdata = '';
            $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $title = $post->post_title;
            $pdata .='<div class="category-boxs">';
               $pdata .='<div class="category-titles"><a href="'.$link.'">' .$title. '</a></div>';
               $pdata .='<div class="category-decs">' .$post->post_content. '</div>';
            $pdata .='</div>';

            $cat_title = get_the_category($post->ID);
            $cat_slug = $cat_title[0]->slug;

            if( !isset($op[$cat_slug]) )
                $op[$cat_slug] = array('first' => '<div class="category-name do-title dot-symbol ">' .$cat_title[0]->cat_name. '</div><div class="category-list">', 'middle' => $pdata, 'last' => '</div>');        
            else
                $op[$cat_slug]['middle'] = $op[$cat_slug]['middle'].$pdata;

        }

        $output = implode('', array_map(function ($entry) {
            return $entry['first'].$entry['middle'].$entry['last'];
        }, $op)); 
    }
    return $output;

}

add_shortcode( 'knowledge_sharing', 'cat_post' ); 

echo do_shortcode( '[knowledge_sharing cat="blog" posts_per_page="5"]' );
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Shafeek

Comment: Yeah..@moumita Accept and upvote the answer will help others to find the solution and would encourage people to answer the questions..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
  $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  var_dump( $categories );
```

You can use
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: array(0) { }
it prints this

Answer (score 0):

You cant use $posts in get_the_category() because $posts is an array contain multiple posts.

First of all, you already have the right category, so why don't you use that directly?

Comment: i am so confuse that i don't understand what you mean to say. can you please explain it.